# How to write code for non-image Logo in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

how do i write a Logo thats made out of pure css so its just like how i would write it in its html form, how does it look in Ruby/Ruby on Rails?

Right now i have this:

```
<div id="logo">
<h1><%= link_to 'Title <span>title</span>'.html_safe, root_path %></h1>
</div>
```

I am new to Ruby and Rails so i have no idea how to include the < span > and i don't think i should be playing with the .Html_safe either.

Comment: Use of html_safe is perfectly fine here, as the input is not user-provided. What's the actual problem?

Comment: Well i don't know anything about html_safe, accept that it should be used in a situation like that. I just wanted to know how to use span and link a css logo without the .html_safe inside of ruby code to avoid any security attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this, I prefer to have more control over the HTML, since including HTML as a string to a helper method is just nasty.

```
<div id="logo">
  <h1>
    <a href="<%= root_path %>">
      Title <span>title</span>
    </a>
  </h1>
</div>
```

The helpers like `link_to` are helpful, but when they make you jump through hoops they aren't worth using.

Comment: This worked for root_path but it didn't for current_user, i click it and get strange gibberish (<User:0x3929718>) do you know how to get it working if i was redirecting to the Profile page with the Logo? in other words <h1><%= link_to 'Title <span>title</span>'.html_safe, current_user %></h1>

Comment: `url_for(current_user)` I believe.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="logo">
  <h1><%= link_to raw('Title <span>title</span>'), root_path %></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Raw tells Rails to display the html you pass, not todisplay it as text. Simply.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `link_to` with a block:

```
<%= link_to root_path do %>
  Title <span>title</span>
<% end %>
```